# Unable to print directory names to file using Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run this Perl script but it is not running as required. It is supposed to store the values of folders name which are in the format of date( example : 11-03-23)

I have some folders placed at this location in my account:
    /hqfs/datastore/files

```
11-02-23   11-02-17    11-04-21
```

I'm storing these in "processed_dirs.dat" file.

But in the output: I got `"pst12345678"` in processed_dirs.dat

And when I printed `$dh`, I got `GLOB(0x12345)` some thing like this:

Please help me in getting the right output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Storable;

# This script to be run 1 time only. Sets up 'processed' directories hash.
# After this script is run, ready to run the daily script.

my $dir = '/hqfs/datastore/files'; # or what ever directory the date-directories are stored in

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Opening failed for directory $dir $!";

my @dir = grep {-d && /^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/ && $_ le '11-07-25'} readdir $dh;

closedir $dh or die "Unable to close $dir $!";

my %processed = map {$_ => 1} @dir;


store \%processed, 'processed_dirs.dat';
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code - what do you expect to find in processed_dirs.dat?

I would suggest verifying @dir is what you expect:
print join ", ", @dir; print "\n";

Comment: it doesn't give any output....what should I do?

Comment: [ysth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) has found the error (below). Try `-d "$dir/$_" && ...` and you should find the directories in `@dir`. The test for directories, `-d`, needs the full path to work correctly (unless the current directory is going to be the directory you are reading).

Comment: In the other script, you would have to correct it also for the same reason. `my @dir = grep {-d "$dir/$_" && /^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/ && !$processed->{$_} } readdir $dh;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an argument for -d.  Try `-d "$dir/$_" && ...`.   (Unless the current directory is always going to be the directory you are reading.)

There is almost no reason to ever use store instead of Storable::nstore.

Why were you trying to print dh?

Comment: I just want to check my perl script functionality. When i printed "processed_dirs.dat"- it doesnt give me the result. So, I was just testing my script.

Comment: to test the functionality, you could `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%processed;`

Comment: So, I need to add just 2 lines in my code---> use Data::Dumper; and print Dumper \%processed;      ----------> thats it?

Comment: $VAR1 = {}; i got this as output

Comment: then fix your -d like I suggested?

Comment: Please check the answer provided by ALex. It really worked well. But he is storing in an array. I need to keep the values in hashtables. Is it possible in his code?

Comment: It really sounded like the next step in your process expects a storable-format file, so no, I don't think you can change that without also changing the script you run next.

Comment: I believe it worked because it doesn't bother to check whether something is a file or a directory, and your problem is with the -d.

Comment: you are awesome man...it works...-d was the problem. You are great

Answer (score 1):

`$dh` is a directory handle object. There's nothing useful you can get by printing it.

The output of `Storable::store` is not intended to be human-readable. If you're expecting something readable in `processed_dirs.dat`, don't... you will need to use `Storable::retrieve` to fetch it back out through perl, or `Data::Dumper` to print out the variable in a readable format.

Comment: so how do i change my perl script now? and what should I type at the command line to test my perl script

Comment: after the script runs, do `perl -MData::Dumper -MStorable -we'print Dumper retrieve("processed_dirs.dat")'`

Comment: perl -MData::Dumper -MStorable -we  -?I didnot get this. what is this? the highlighhted portion is not clear

Comment: I copied the whole line and I got Var={};

Comment: equivalent to `perl -we'use Data::Dumper; use Storable; ...'` only shorter

Answer (score 0):

This implementation works and gives you accurate information.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $dir = '/Volumes/Data/Alex/';
opendir $dh , $dir 
    or die "Cannot open dir: $!";
my @result = ();
foreach ( readdir $dh )
{
    if ( ! /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/ ) { next; } else { push @result , $_; }
}
```

Comment: I need to store the name of the folders in a hashtable. How do I do that?

Comment: processed_dirs.dat- in my previous implementation , i was storing here

Comment: I checked your code....and it runs perfectly fine. But Is it possible if I keep it in hashtable?

Comment: This doesn't take in account directories before the specified date.

Comment: yes Chris, there is one thing need to be added in your script to make it work. -->   -d "$dir/$_" && ... and it works then